# ServletContext Attribute : Thread Safety test not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to check thread safety of a servletContext attribute. I know that ServletContext attributes are available in whole Web-App and can be accessed and modified by anyone, So I am trying to test the negative as  scenario (i.e. context attribute was set by someone and updated by other) But it is not working.

Adding Code Snippet of actual code.

**Servlet A**

```
 public class TestContextAttributeThreadSafety extends HttpServlet {
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {        
    //synchronized(getServletContext()){
    getServletContext().setAttribute("safety", "SetByThreadA");
    //}
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("threadSafetyJsp.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

**Servlet B**

```
public class TestContextAttributeThreadSafetyB extends HttpServlet {
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {        
    //synchronized(getServletContext()){
    getServletContext().setAttribute("safety", "SetByThreadB");
    //}
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("threadSafetyJsp.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

**Index.html**

```
  <form name =" testThreadSafetyA" method ="GET" action="./TestContextAttr">
        <br><br>
        <h3> Test Context Attribute Thread Safety A</h3>
        <input type="SUBMIT" value ="submit">
    </form>

    <form name =" testThreadSafetyB" method ="GET" action="./TestContextAttrB">
        <br><br>
        <h3> Test Context Attribute Thread Safety B</h3>
        <input type="SUBMIT" value ="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

**weB.XML**

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>/TestContextAttribute</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.incredible.controller.TestContextAttributeThreadSafety</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestContextAttributeB</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.incredible.controller.TestContextAttributeThreadSafetyB</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>/TestContextAttribute</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestContextAttr</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestContextAttributeB</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestContextAttrB</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**threadSafetyJsp.jsp**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Thread Safety Test : </h1>     

 <%out.print(getServletContext().getAttribute("safety"));%>
     </body>
</html>
```

Now I am running this app in Two Different Browsers. From One browser,I am clicking on first Submit button to get output  **SetByThreadA** and from other browser, I am clicking 2nd submit button Which gives Output **SetByThreadB**.

Now, After clicking 2nd submit button, ServletContext attribute *safety* was updated by ThreadB. So, I go back to first browser where output of ThreadA is ( i.e. SetByThreadA )and click on page refresh button. Since It will again load jSP page, which is fetching value of ServletContext attribute *safety*, I am expecting the updated value of ServletContext on first Browser i.e. **SetByThreadB**. But, it is still showing **SetByThreadA**. So, I am not getting why thevalue is not getting updated. Please help

Comment: How could we? You haven't posted any code.

Comment: I have added whole Description of what I am doing. and main codePoints. isn't it sufficient ? Also, code is on another machine

Comment: @JB Nizet, I have added code snippets, Please answer now.

Comment: Refreshing the page will send the same GET request to ./TestContextAttr, and will thus invoke the TestContextAttributeThreadSafety servlet, which will set the servlet context attribute to "SetByThreadA" again, and will then forward to the JSP, which will display its new value: "SetByThreadA". You need to send a request to a third servlet (or to the JSP directly) that only displays the context attribute, and doesn't set it before displaying it.

Comment: @JBNizet, I was able to get the expected result by passing the request to first ServletA/ServletB --> Result.jsp --> ThreadSafetyResult.jsp, where I got the servletContext Attribute and When I refreshed the page second time, It updated the result.

Now, in order to solve this problem using "synchronized" block, I put setAttribute() in that block and tested again, but It didn't solve the problem. Can you suggest some way to test this whole behavoiur ?

Comment: Once again, I don't know what --> means. You obviously screwed up again. This works fine, but your test is incorrect. Just understand that if you don't have a URL that ends with .jsp, in the address bar of your browser, refreshing that page will not only execute the JSP. It will execute the servlet mapped to the URL again, and thus set the attribute again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80240/discussion-between-incredible-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to check thread safety of a servletContext attribute.

No you're not. You're not testing any such thing as thread safety here. You're just testing `setAttribute()` sequentially. There's no guarantee anywhere that these two pieces of code won't execute on the *same* thread. It's pointless. It works, and if it doesn't there is nothing you can do about it.

Don't test the platform.

Comment: the idea is to check the need of Synchronized block. .Since this attribute can be read from anywhere in the app and by any servlet/ thread, it can be updated by anyone. So, if you have any solution using which I can produce this scenario and then I can solve it by using synchronized block, Please tell

Comment: The question can be answer analytically. You don't need to test for it. Is the map holding the context attributes thread-safe? The Servlet Speification provides the answer. You're going about this entirely the wrong way. If you had consulted the Specification in the first place you would already have your answer.

Comment: I am learning servlets and as I learnt, these attributes are not thread safe and if I set attribute, this can be updated by other servlet or request or anyone who has access to ServletContext. So, the suggested solution was to use "synchronized" block while updating the attribute, which will prevent this from happening.

So, I wanted to test this scenario to make sure that there is a problem and putting attributes in snychronized block works. That is where I am struggling on how to create problem and then solve it using synchronized block :)

Comment: It won't prevent it from happening. It will *delay* it. If you update the attribute it will get updated. That's what it's for. To get updated. There is a serious misunderstanding here somewhere. In any case you aren't testing what you think you're testing. The real question is why you're using Servlet context attributes at all and trying to make them thread-safe. They aren't. They can't be. They are application-scoped. Maybe you should be using request scoped attributes.